# Inverse scattering of sine-Gordon equation to get 2-soliton solution: Which potential?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soliton-theory

It is well-known that for the Sine-Gordon equation, $u_{xt}=\sin u$, if we start with the initial condition resp. initial potential $q(x,0)=\lambda\operatorname{sech}(\lambda x+\mu)$, one can use the inverse scattering transform to get the 1-soliton solution
$$
u(x,t)=-4\arctan(e^{\mu+\lambda x+t/\lambda}).\tag{1}
$$
(For $\lambda>0$ it is called kink.)

Now I would like to know with which potential we need to start to get the 2-soliton solution (via inverse scattering)
$$
u(x,t)=4\arctan\left(\left(\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\right)\frac{e^{\theta_1}-e^{\theta_2}}{1+e^{\theta_1+\theta_2}}\right),\tag{2}
$$
where $\theta_i:=\lambda_i x+t/\lambda_i +\mu_i, i=1,2$.

Something which came into my mind was just something like
$$
q(x,0)=\sum_{i=1}^2\lambda_i\operatorname{sech}(\lambda_i x +\mu_i)
$$
but this is far from being justified...

Comment: Do you have the reference of the formula for the 2-soliton solution? I would like to check something that seems weird

Comment: "Solitons: An Introduction" by P.G. Drazin   - - What is weird?

Comment: Q6.17, pg.166, right?

Comment: Absolutely right, yes

Comment: It's ok, interesting, mmm..

Comment: What are you concerned about if I may ask?

Comment: It seems that your guess about the potential is correct, but I'm trying to fill the argument, it will take some time

Comment: Thanks for trying! I am trying, too:)